# Trying to render an image sent with NodeJS in React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I would like to render an image sent with a nodeJS server in React Frontend but my code doesn't work.

Here is the object recived in frontend called Photo:
[image]

As you can see is a Buffer fut that's what appears:
[image]

Here is the code where I'm trying to render it, ImageProgress is a styled img:

```js
<ImageProgress src={Photo} />
```

If anyone know how to fix it, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: can you share the code for this file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should specify Photo type

```js
src={`data:${Photo.type};base64,${Buffer.from(Photo.data).toString('base64')}`}
```

Comment: I edit my comment try again and try to specify the image type